# Scenario if in input numbers are repeat

Tags: python, list, input

Code:

```
n = int(input("Type n: "))

def some_function(n):
    numbers, numbers_sum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 45
    while True:
        digit = n % 10
        n //= 10
        if digit in numbers:
            numbers.remove(digit)
            numbers_sum -= digit
        else:
            break
    return numbers_sum

print(some_function(n))
```

**Program needs to print the sum of numbers that are not found in the input.**

I covered the scenario when numbers are not repeating and for this scenario if the input is **234567890** output is **1** .
But don't have an idea for scenario when numbers are repeating.Etc. if the input is **22334567890** or **223344556677889900** output still needs to be **1** but it's not.

P.S.
I can't do it with strings.
I know 0 doesn't make difference because we are doing with - and +.

Comment: Please provide information on what you are trying to achieve. You posted the code without any information about its goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.Code:

```
n, finish = int(input("Type n: ")), 0
dig_list, num_list = [], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def sum(n):
    while n > 0:
        digit = n % 10
        n //= 10
        dig_list.append(digit)
    for i in range (0, 11):
        if i in dig_list:
            num_list.remove(i)
    return num_list

for e in (sum(n)):
    finish += e

print(finish)
```

**Purpose of code.**

**Explanation:**
First, we create 2 lists.
The first one(dig_list) has no elements and there we are gonna put all digits of input(n).
The second list is a list of numbers from 0 to 9(num_list).
Then we put all digits of n in the first list.Then using **for loop** we go through the first list.If numbers from 0 to 9 are found in the first list we remove them from the second list.
In the end, we save the sum(+) of the remaining elements of the second list to a variable sum.

Answer (score 0):

the easier way to do it is to transform it to a string and do set operations

```
>>> n=22334567890
>>> numbers=set("123456789")
>>> numbers-set(str(n))
{'1'}
>>>
```

and then transform back to integers

```
>>> sum(map(int,{'1'}))
1
>>>
```

if you don't want the string conversion, just make a function that give you the digits of the numbers and do the same

```
>>> def digits(n): #this is a generator function
        if n==0:
            yield 0
        while n:
            n,d = divmod(n,10)
            yield d


>>> n=22334567890            
>>> numbers=set(range(10))
>>> numbers
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
>>> list(digits(n))
[0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]
>>> 
>>> numbers - set(digits(n))
{1}
>>> sum({1})
1
>>>
```

Comment: I can't do it with strings.Ty anyway.

Comment: the same can be done with numbers too